# COM interop DLL file located separate from exe file

Tags: .net, delphi, dll, com-interop

There may be questions already have my answer, I'm a just newbie, andI couldn't find answers that exactly solve my problem.

I'm developing an app with Delphi xe5, which uses .NET assembly.

I registered the assembly using Regasm.exe.
    \Regasm.exe /tlb TestLib.dll

Next, from the Conponent menu of Delphi I selected Import Component, then Imported Type Library, then created TestLib_TLB.pas file.
Adding TestLib_TLB.pas into the Project, through the pas file I can call functions/procedures the assembly offers.

The problem is that the assembly's API calls would fail if the DLL is located in a different folder from the app exe file.

I tried to register the DLL file into GAC using gacutil.exe, but that didn't solve the problem.

What's wrong with the process above?

Comment: How do you plan to deploy this app to end users?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for your comment, I plan to deploy this app manually - just copy files and execute some commands optionally if needed.

Comment: So why do you object to placing the DLL alongside the EXE? FWIW, I think the regasm registration will register the location of the DLL when you register it. Place it where you want it to be and then call regasm.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The assembly file is supplied by a GIS software vender along with lots of related files, so I want to separate our EXE folder and the GIS application folder(in addition GIS application is optional).

Comment: What location do you see in the COM registry? Perhaps regasm only writes the full path if you supply the full path.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
I'm not sure where I can find location in the COM registry.
I see attributes below in the registry. assembly DLL file name is Aqua_F.dll in this case.

    Assembly
      Aqua_F, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Class
      Aqua_F.AquaFInterface
    RuntimeVersion
      v4.0.30319

Comment: Look under HKCR with your component's GUID

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I looked under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and found the GUID. And I found sub folders Implemented Categories, InprocServer32, InprocServer32/1.0.0.0, ProgId. But I can't find the location...

Comment: What's the default value of the InprocServer32 key? You need to spend some time learning about COM reg.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The default value of the InprocServer32 key is mscoree.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Regasm sintax should be

```
regasm TestLib.dll /tlb:TestLib.tlb
```

this would register TestLib.dll and create and register TestLib.tlb.

After this you should not move, rename, replace or delete TestLib.dll or TestLib.tlb, because their location and COM interfaces are now written inside the registry. If you have to, first unregister the "old" component

```
regasm TestLib.dll /unregister /tlb:TestLib.tlb
```

then put in place the new dll and register it again.

```
regasm SomeFolder\TestLib.dll /tlb:AnotherFolder\TestLib.tlb
```